# Why creating been in Spring occurs with error?

Tags: spring

Hello I am creating program which will communicate and send information using channel. When I run program it doesn't work.

Errors:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-05-02 13:47:37.938 ERROR 12584 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldQueueProducer' defined in file [C:\workspace\target\classes\edu\producer\HelloWorldQueueProducer.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAutoConfiguration$JmsTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisConnectionFactoryConfiguration$SimpleConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'cachingJmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create ActiveMQConnectionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelloWorldQueueProducer {
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)

    public void sendHello() {
        HelloMessage message = HelloMessage.builder()
                .id(HelloMessage.nextId())
                .createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .message("Hello world!")
                .build();
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsConfig.QUEUE_HELLO_WORLD, message);
        System.out.println("HelloWorldQueueProducer.sendHello - sent message: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read your stacktrace - the problem is in creating `jmsConnectionFactory` because of missing parameter `jmsTemplate`

Comment: jmsTemplate is defined
in HelloWorldQueueProducer - public class HelloWorldQueueProducer {
    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about it, but have you defined the necessary properties in your application.properties? You need to set them like this i. e.

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=localhost
spring.artemis.port=61616
spring.artemis.user=developer
spring.artemis.password=developer
jms.queue.destination=myqueue
```

Otherwise the autoconfiguration of spring boot wouldn't bootstrap the necessary beans. I had this problem once.

Comment: Yesterday I was praying to programming god I had it but not everything.
Lack of user and password.
It Works!
thank you